# How to list all images in uploads directory except those that are attached to any post

Tags: theme-development, php, functions

I've got code in my functions.php which parses the WP uploads folder and lists all images it finds there. Is it possible to place a filter here that would exclude any image that is already "attached" to a post?

eg: "List all images in folder "uploads" where image is not found in (attached images)"

Comment: Can you specify if you need to list all files on disk or would it be sufficient to refer to those files that are namely stored in the database?

Comment: @hakre: All files on disc that are of type (jpg, gif, png) and are location in folder "wp-content/uploads" (non recursive to subfolders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Media / Edit, there's a means to list them, so I suggest you reuse the existing API.

Else, a general method, which works anywhere, is to run a db query with a left join:

```
select ID
  from foo
left join bar
    on whatever
 where condition
   and bar.ID is null;
```

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/upload.php#L37

Comment: @Denis, that was my first thought. Looking at wp-admin/upload.php for clues. Looks like the $lost variable on line 23 might hold clues, yes?... (WP 3.0.1)

Comment: Woops... Looks like I miss-touched the ipad's screen and deleted your comment. Sorry bout that. The file that does the magic in wp is above.

Comment: Btw, there also is a meta for each attachment. It contains the path relative to the uploads folder.

Comment: @Denis, how about this >> run query to collect an array of items in wp_postmeta where meta_key = "_wp_attached_file", then exclude any images from the output stream whose filename is found in the array...

Comment: $excludeImages = $wpdb->query("Select meta_value FROM $wpdb->wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'"); > Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: Re your fatal error, you'll need to include wp-load.php to initialize wpdb.

Comment: @Denis, this is being called from functions.php. It has access to $wpdb in that scope right?

Comment: Thanks to Mike Schinkel. The problem was I had not set global $wpdb inside my function.